# PHP: is doing a lot of file_exist() calls disk-intensive?

Tags: php

I want to check a certain directory to see if a file exists, and if it does not, copy the missing file from another directory. Basically syncing two folders. I can do so easily with PHP, using the `file_exists()` function. However, the directory exists of some 20,000 files, so I feel this could be bad for the hard drive (a lot of reads???). Does this make any sense, or is there nothing to worry about?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to sync with PHP? There is `rsync`.

Comment: If it proves to be a concern (I don't know if it does), you could `readdir` or `glob` the contents of the directories into arrays and check whether it exists from within PHP.

Comment: I need to do this for a specific application. But @casey-hope, your solution will work! Thanks! If you could put this in an answer I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it proves to be a concern (and I don't know if it does), you could `readdir` or `glob` the contents of the directories into arrays and check whether it exists from within PHP. That way you only read from disk once rather than 20,000 times.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is not well suited for such tasks.

You may try executing some shell commands, like [`rsync`](https://serverfault.com/search?q=rsync) or `xcopy`:

```
exec('xcopy c:\\mydir d:\\mydir /e/i', $a, $a1);
```

Most probably, some VCS like [`git`](/search?q=[git]) would be the best solution in this case.

If you still need to do this in PHP, two things to remember:

- this will not be optimal solution (slow)
- anything that takes a lot of resources can be optimized using some kind of cache (e.g. creating a list of files to compare)

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment on whether calling `file_exists()` for that many files is something to worry about, but you may want to consider `is_file()` instead. Since the results are cached it could be considered a less intensive way of doing what you want.